# How to make simple Fuel Consumption Calculator in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to write a simple fuel consumption calculator with user inputs. I'm having trouble to make the calculation.

It should be:

```
100 x Fuel spent liters(L) ÷ Kilometers (km) driven
```

I've done inputs and tried different types of calculations, but nothing is working. Here is what I have so far on my index view:

```
<h1>Fuel Consumption Calculator</h1>
<div class="calculator">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="no1">Liters (l):</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no1" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="no2">Kilometers driven: (km)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="no2" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Laske" name="tot">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tot">Total:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tot" name="tot" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

Do you guys have any tip?

Comment: You created the markup for the inputs - but what about doing the actual calculation? Have you submitted the form - or tried to calculate it in JS? What went wrong with your approach?

Comment: `Do you guys have any tip?` <- You should write code to actually do the calculation you want and display the results. As @mason mentioned, all you have are inputs. HTML is a markup language, it does not have behavior. You need to write some code in either javascript (or a superset of javascript) *or* make a call to your server and do the calculation there. Doing it in javascript will be the easiest approach for you. There are many tutorials on how to add behavior to a static html page using javascript. Make an attempt and if you get stuck come back and show what is not working.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant if anyone had tip what to try next, for example on click event, or do a class, or do the calculation in controller. Wasn't sure what would be the best option.

Comment: Hi! I got it working with JavaScript code, thank you!! :)